# DatePicker item height in flyout

Tags: xaml, datepicker, windows-runtime, uwp

How can I adjust height of the item (LoopingSelectorItem) in the DatePicker's flyout in Universal Windows Platform? It's always 44px.

[image]

Comment: did you try using styles?

Comment: I wish someone knows what exactly I can change, because i've tried everything and it didn't help, so I came here to ask. P.S. I'm not a noob in xaml and etc. at all.

Comment: Then i think you only have an option .. Go to blend .. Edit a Copy and restlye it ..

Comment: Style doesn't affect on this height. It's always 44px. I've changed everything: DatePickerStyle -> DatePickerFlyoutPresenterStyle -> LoopingSelectorStyle -> LoopingSelectorItemStyle. Maybe it's in control's code.

Comment: try using the visualtree helper .. or try using the visualtrere class to find all the child elements .. hope it will give some clue

Answer (score 0):

this for TimePickerFlyout but I hope to help you

```
    <Style TargetType="TimePickerFlyoutPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="242" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="242" />
        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="396" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="TimePickerFlyoutPresenter" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource DateTimeFlyoutBorderThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TimePickerFlyoutPresenter">
                    <Border x:Name="Background"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        MaxHeight="396">
                        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                           </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Grid >
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="FirstPickerHostColumn" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="SecondPickerHostColumn" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" x:Name="ThirdPickerHostColumn" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<!--********************************this line should change, Height Property-->
                                <Rectangle x:Name="HighlightRect" Height="44" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightListAccentLowBrush}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
<!---->  
                                </Rectangle>

                                <Border x:Name="FirstPickerHost" Grid.Column="0" >
                                    <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                            <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClosePopUp}"/>
                                        </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </Border>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="FirstPickerSpacing" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="2" Grid.Column="1" >

                                </Rectangle>
                                <Border x:Name="SecondPickerHost" Grid.Column="2" >
                                    <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                            <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClosePopUp}"/>
                                        </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </Border>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="SecondPickerSpacing" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="2" Grid.Column="3" >

                                </Rectangle>
                                <Border x:Name="ThirdPickerHost" Grid.Column="4" >
                                    <interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                        <interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Tapped">
                                            <interactcore:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClosePopUp}"/>
                                        </interactcore:EventTriggerBehavior>
                                    </interact:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                </Border>

                            </Grid>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="1"  Visibility="Collapsed">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Height="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Fill="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />

                                <Button x:Name="AcceptButton" Grid.Column="0" Content="&#xE8FB;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
                                <Button x:Name="DismissButton" Grid.Column="1" Content="&#xE711;" FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}" FontSize="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{StaticResource DateTimePickerFlyoutButtonStyle}" Margin="0,2,0,0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```